# how to change widget id programmatically on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout

how to change widget id programmatically?
example
i wanted to change XML code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Title"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="roboto"/>
```

into

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/EvolvedTitle"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="roboto"/>
```

with java code in **mainActivity.java**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible ,

Try saving your reserved id like so

```
<resources>
    <item name="EvolvedTitle" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Than you can find your first id and set the new one like so :

```
    TextView tv = (TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.Title);
    tv.setid(R.id.EvolvedTitle);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: nice answer there, but how to make it dynamically? example EvolvedTitle1, EvolvedTitle2, EvolvedTitle3, ...... ,EvolvedTitle(n+1)

Comment: for what purpuse ? i don't think it's possible but what are you trying to do ?